Visual representation(s) for variable length m-tuples
I'm working with a dataset of sequences, each 200 characters long. Within these sequences are embedded 10-character patterns (P1 to P5). The co-occurrence of these patterns varies across sequences - some contain just one pattern (e.g. P1), while others have multiple patterns (e.g. P1, P2, P3).
The current methods like Venn diagrams and basic graph models primarily capture co-occurance frequency of patterns (P1 and P2 vs P1,P2,P3 etc.) and pairwise relationships between patterns but cannot adequately represent complex co-occurrences involving more than two patterns (m-tuples where m>2) for a visualization. While visualizations like upset plots come closer, they still don't provide an insightful visualization of the compositional relationships between P1 to P5.
I need visualization or network analysis techniques that can effectively capture and visualize the frequency and complexity of m-tuple (m>2) pattern co-occurrences within the sequences. I'm particularly interested in methods going beyond pairwise interactions to include higher-order relationships. The goal is to better understand and visualize how these patterns co-exist, potentially revealing intricate relationships or frequent combinations critical for further analysis.
What is a good computational context to look for insight here? Methods focusing on social network analysis? Graph theory? Could this be better suited in the context of natural language processing where P1 to P5 could be posed as words, and sequences as sentences?
